# Better way to add column values combinations to data frame in PySpark

Tags: dataframe, performance, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataset that contains 3 columns, `id`, `day`, `value`. I need to add rows with zeros in `value` for all combinations of `id` and `day`.

```
# Simplified version of my data frame
data = [("1", "2020-04-01", 5), 
        ("2", "2020-04-01", 5), 
        ("3", "2020-04-02", 4)]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data,['id','day', 'value'])
```

What I have come up with is:

```
# Create all combinations of id and day
ids= df.select('id').distinct()
days = df.select('day').distinct()
full = ids.crossJoin(days)

# Add combinations back to df filling value with zeros
df_full = df.join(full, ['id', 'day'], 'rightouter')\
    .na.fill(value=0,subset=['value'])
```

Which outputs what I need:

```
>>> df_full.orderBy(['id','day']).show()
+---+----------+-----+
| id|       day|value|
+---+----------+-----+
|  1|2020-04-01|    5|
|  1|2020-04-02|    0|
|  2|2020-04-01|    5|
|  2|2020-04-02|    0|
|  3|2020-04-01|    0|
|  3|2020-04-02|    4|
+---+----------+-----+
```

The problem is that both of these operations a very computationally expensive. When I'm running it with my full data, it gives me a job that an order of magnitude larger than something that usually takes a couple of hours to run.

Is there a more efficient way of doing this? Or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Do you know anything about the data. Are the dates or id:s contiguous for instance? Or is everything random? How large is your real world dataset, i.e. approximately how many rows and unique dates/id:s?

Comment: Hi @Molotch, the data is around 5x10^9 rows with 5 million ids and 61 days. But I'm not sure contiguous means in this context (I've tried googling without much success).

Comment: By contiguous I meant there are no gaps, i.e. if the first date is 2021-01-01 and the last date is 2021-01-10 you know all dates in between are in the dataset.

Comment: Since you know the dates and there weren't that many of them I would try to repartition the dataset by id so all rows per id end up in the same partition. Then sortPartitions by id and date so they're in the right order. Then finally apply the known dates in a function you pass to a mapPartitions call. The function would just add a row for each missing date.

Comment: Hi @Molotch, that actually makes a lot of sense! I haven't actually tried to implement it, but I'm not sure about the function to use on `mapPartitions()`. Something like the `'rightouter'` join? Is that what you meant?

Comment: what is the purpose of having a zero value row for every id, date combination? Trying to get a better picture of the data.

Comment: I wrote an answer, check below. This solution partitions and sorts the data once, everything else takes place on the same executor and should be more performant than joining. Though you pay the overhead of serializing to and from Python.

Answer (score 5):

That's the way I would implement. Just a point, both dataframes must have the same schema, otherwise `stack` function will raise an error

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as f


# Simplified version of my data frame
data = [("1", "2020-04-01", 5), 
        ("2", "2020-04-01", 5), 
        ("3", "2020-04-02", 4)]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ['id', 'day', 'value'])

# Creating a dataframe with all distinct days
df_days = df.select(f.col('day').alias('r_day')).distinct()

# Self Join to find all combinations
df_final = df.join(df_days, on=df['day'] != df_days['r_day'])
# +---+----------+-----+----------+
# | id|       day|value|     r_day|
# +---+----------+-----+----------+
# |  1|2020-04-01|    5|2020-04-02|
# |  2|2020-04-01|    5|2020-04-02|
# |  3|2020-04-02|    4|2020-04-01|
# +---+----------+-----+----------+

# Unpivot dataframe
df_final = df_final.select('id', f.expr('stack(2, day, value, r_day, cast(0 as bigint)) as (day, value)'))
df_final.orderBy('id', 'day').show()
```

Output:

```
+---+----------+-----+
| id|       day|value|
+---+----------+-----+
|  1|2020-04-01|    5|
|  1|2020-04-02|    0|
|  2|2020-04-01|    5|
|  2|2020-04-02|    0|
|  3|2020-04-01|    0|
|  3|2020-04-02|    4|
+---+----------+-----+
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to be any faster at least locally with the simplified data. I'll run a benchmark comparison to be sure. But I am curious to understand a bit the intuition behind why this should be faster (pardon my spark ignorance). Thank you!

Comment: Probably the fact that I'm avoiding one step more like `crossJoin`, would be faster, but of course, only testing if your real data.

Comment: @LeonardoViotti I did an update to simplify my code. Check it again and please, let me know if it is faster than your solution

Comment: I did some benchmarking and unfortunately your answer took close to 7x more time, aprox. 2000s vs aprox. 300s with my question's code. That is on my local setup using just the mock 3x3 data frame. :/

Answer (score 0):

Something like this. You could, I keep the first row separate since it's more clear what happens. You could add it to the "main loop" though.

```
data = [
    ("1", date(2020, 4, 1), 5),
    ("2", date(2020, 4, 2), 5),
    ("3", date(2020, 4, 3), 5),
    ("1", date(2020, 4, 3), 5),
]


df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["id", "date", "value"])

row_dates = df.select("date").distinct().collect()

dates = [item.asDict()["date"] for item in row_dates]


def map_row(dates: List[date]) -> Callable[[Iterator[Row]], Iterator[Row]]:
    dates.sort()

    def inner(partition):
        last_row = None

        for row in partition:
            # fill in missing dates for first row in partition
            if last_row is None:
                for day in dates:
                    if day < row.date:
                        yield Row(row.id, day, 0)
                    else:
                        # set current row as last row, yield current row and break out of the loop
                        last_row = row
                        yield row
                        break
            else:
                # if current row has same id as last row
                if last_row.id == row.id:
                    # yield dates between last and current
                    for day in dates:
                        if day > last_row.date and day < row.date:
                            yield Row(row.id, day, 0)
                    
                    # set current as last and yield current
                    last_row = row
                    yield row

                else:
                    # if current row is new id
                    for day in dates:
                        # run potential remaining dates for last_row.id
                        if day > last_row.date:
                            yield Row(last_row.id, day, 0)

                    for day in dates:
                        # fill in missing dates before row.date
                        if day < row.date:
                            yield Row(row.id, day, 0)                    
                        else:
                            # unt so weiter
                            last_row = row
                            yield row
                            break

    return inner


rdd = (
    df.repartition(1, "id")
    .sortWithinPartitions("id", "date")
    .rdd.mapPartitions(map_row(dates))
)
new_df = spark.createDataFrame(rdd)
new_df.show(10, False)
```